# Migration Cloudera Kafka (CDK) to Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking to migrate a small 4 node Kafka cluster with about 300GB of data on the each brokers to a new cluster. The problem is we are currently running Cloudera's flavor of Kafka (CDK) and we would like to run Apache Kafka. For the most part CDK is very similar to Apache Kafka but I am trying to figure out the best way to migrate. I originally looked at using MirrorMaker, but to my understanding it will re-process messages once we cut over the consumers to the new cluster so I think that is out. I was wondering if we could spin up a new Apache Kafka cluster and add it to the CDK cluster (not sure how this will work yet, if at all) then decommission the CDK server one at a time. Otherwise I am out of ideas other than spinning up a new Apache Kafka cluster and just making code changes to every producer/consumer to point to the new cluster. which I am not really a fan of as it will cause down time.

Currently running 3.1.0 which is equivalent to Apache Kafka 1.0.1

Comment: From what I understand, Cloudera doesn't manage a different installation of Kafka. They may backport additional patches from Apache project, but it's still all the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker would copy the data, but not consumer offsets, so they'd be left at their configured auto.offset.reset policies.

> I was wondering if we could spin up a new Apache Kafka cluster and add it to the CDK cluster

If possible, that would be the most effective way to migrate the cluster. For each new broker, give it a unique broker ID and the same Zookeeper connection string as the others, then it'll be part of the same cluster.

Then, you'll need to manually run the partition reassignment tool to move all existing topic partitions off of the old brokers and onto the new ones as data will not automatically be replicated

Alternatively, you could try shutting down the CDK cluster, backing up the data directories onto new brokers, then starting the same version of Kafka from your CDK on those new machines (as the stored log format is important).

Also make sure that you backup a copy of the server.properties files for the new brokers

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 for the tips I will test out adding new brokers and see how the CDK cluster reacts. Your alternative solution may work too but will have downtime but may be unavoidable able at this point.